# insert into with select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello I would like to insert the values ​​in a column from a select query

```
insert into (cmts) stat_alert 
values(SELECT stat_alert.cell,stat_alert.cmts,cell_cmt.cmts FROM stat_alert`LEFT OUTER JOIN cell_cmt ON cell_cmt.`cell`=stat_alert.cell WHERE stat_alert.`cell`=cell_cmt.cell )
```

I have syntax error
who can help me??

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `VALUES` keyword and round brackets:

```
INSERT INTO <table name> (<comma separated column list>)
SELECT <comma separated column list> FROM <table name>
```

Read the [`INSERT ... SELECT` syntax from the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `INSERT INTO otherTable (cols) SELECT <yourColumns> FROM <yourtable>` not `INSERT INTO ... VALUES()`:

```
insert into stat_alert (cmts)  -- list your columns here to insert into
SELECT cell_cmt.cmts  -- your values to be inserted are here
FROM stat_alert
LEFT OUTER JOIN cell_cmt 
    ON cell_cmt.`cell`=stat_alert.cell 
WHERE stat_alert.`cell`=cell_cmt.cell
```

Comment: @user1794019 what is the error?  What is the table structure of `stat_alert`?

Comment: Its works :) thank you INSERT INTO stat_alert (cmts)
SELECT cell_cmt.cmts 
FROM stat_alert
LEFT OUTER JOIN cell_cmt 
    ON cell_cmt.`cell`=stat_alert.cell 
WHERE stat_alert.`cell`=cell_cmt.cell

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have:

1. The column list before the table name
2. One column to insert into, but three columns selected
3. A `values` keyword when none is needed in this kind of query.

Comment: INSERT INTO stat_alert (cmts)
SELECT cell_cmt.cmts 
FROM stat_alert
LEFT OUTER JOIN cell_cmt 
    ON cell_cmt.`cell`=stat_alert.cell 
WHERE stat_alert.`cell`=cell_cmt.cell